# Minified code using Webpack and UglifyJsPlugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying do add multiple files into bundle and minify it. Webpack doesn't give me any error, code is compiled and minified but it doesn't work.

[image]

**My webpack config:**

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
    './js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
    './vendor/bootstrap4alpha/js/tether.min.js',
    './vendor/bootstrap4alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js',
    './vendor/chartjs/Chart.bundle.min.js',
    './vendor/chartjs/utils.js',
    './vendor/spincrement/jquery.spincrement.min.js',
    './js/adminux.js'
  ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      mangle: true
    })
  ]
};
```

When I run my app in the browser, it doesn't work and give me an error in console:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be
>   included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

So it looks like jquery is not in bundle but it is. When I add jquery in html file, it outputs next error with tether.min.js

Comment: Double check on the folder structure. I mean wherever you are keeping those js files. Looks like it's not able to fetch the files from the specified location.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary if anything would be wrong with files paths I would propably get webpack error

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap needs to use the `$`, it's not a global variable in webpack.

you can use `bootstrap-webpack` instead.

or use webpack ProvidePlugin to define a global $:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    // Automtically detect jQuery and $ as free var in modules
    // and inject the jquery library
    // This is required by many jquery plugins
    jQuery: "jquery",
    $: "jquery"
})
```